# How to create simulator for BLE device to communicate via Bluetooth?

Tags: android, bluetooth, kotlin

I am creating an application where I need to pass data over Bluetooth, but I don't have a BLE device. I want to use common BLE characteristics to pass data over Bluetooth. Is there any simulator available for this? Where can I test my application? I am developing this application in Kotlin, please, give me a solution accordingly to that. In short, I need an application which should behave like a beacon.

Comment: Just mock BLE calls yourself. Having BT simulator is equivalent to mocking those calls yourself.

Comment: Did you find any solution